# API Management <forward-request> fails with error message "Cannot access a closed Stream."

Tags: azure-api-management

As part of a requirement to inspect to request body of our API Management proxy requests, I have added a call to `context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true)`. However, after this change, my `<forward-request>` policies fail with `Cannot access a closed Stream`.

The error message does not hold many clues, but I think the stream, it refers to, is the inbound request body. For this reason I used the `preserveContent: true` overload, but it fails regardless.

What are some other sources that may cause the stream to become closed and how can I keep it open, so that `<forward-request>` can forward the request body as well?

Comment: Could you attach your policy in full? I'm having a hard time reproducing this.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by inserting a `<set-body>` policy in the end of my `<inbound>` section like this: `<set-body>@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("Request.Body"))</set-body>`.